# Incomplete type --> Can't Access Pointer value from my object

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

I'm trying to access one of my pointers within my class, however I can't seem to even get VS to acknowledge the pointer is there.

```
private:
   ForwardTo* forward;
```

and here's how I grab it from the class

```
ForwardTo& Persons::getForwardTo() const
{
    return *forward;
}
```

The ForwardTo type is an inherited class that typically reads:

```
    class ForwardToTwo : public ForwardTo
{

public:
    ForwardToTwo(unsigned int strategy);
    virtual std::vector<std::string> forwardMessage(Persons& person, Message& message);
    unsigned int getStrategy() const { return strategy;};
private:
    unsigned int strategy;
};
```

and finally, here's how I'm trying to access the pointer

```
listOfPersons.at(i).getForwardTo()->forwardMessage(listOfPersons.at(i), tempMessage);
```

This style of access worked previously for my OTHER pointer in my class that acts exactly this same as this one.

While typing the line to access the pointer out in VS, intelliSense picks up all the functions up to `getForwardTo()`, and after that, the dot operator/arrow operator don't bring up any access to functions.

Thanks again for all help.

(edit, I'm aware the function `fordwardMessage()` function will return a vector, I was just typing in the VS until intelliSense failed to detect the accessible functions)

(edit 2, I've tried both the `.` operator and the `->` operator, yet neither allow intelliSense to detect any functions.)

(edit 3, additional code:
Here is my Persons Class Header:

```
#ifndef PERSONS_HPP
#define PERSONS_HPP

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <map>

#include "Message.hpp"

#include "TypeOne.hpp"
#include "TypeTwo.hpp"
#include "TypeThree.hpp"
#include "TypeFour.hpp"
#include "TypeFive.hpp"

class ForwardTo;
class ForwardToOne;
class ForwardToTwo;
class ForwardToThree;

class Persons
{
public:

    Persons();
    ~Persons();

    void setEmailAddress(std::string email);
    std::string getEmailAddress() const;
    const std::vector<std::string>& getContactList() const;

    void addMessageSeen(Message message);
    void addMessageContent(MessageContent mc);
    void addInboxMessage(Message message);
    void addContact(std::string contact);

    void viewContact(const std::vector<std::string>& contacts);
    void bumpContact();

    void setMessageTypeOne();
    void setMessageTypeTwo(unsigned int type);
    void setMessageTypeThree(unsigned int quality);
    void setMessageTypeFour(unsigned int type, unsigned int quality);
    void setMessageTypeFive();

    void setForwardTypeOne(unsigned int strategy);
    void setForwardTypeTwo(unsigned int strategy);
    void setForwardTypeThree(unsigned int strategy);

    void printPersonsObj();
    std::list<Message> getInbox() const;

    MessageType& getForwardWhen() const;
    ForwardTo& getForwardTo() const;

private:

    std::map<MessageContent, unsigned int>  messageList;
    std::list<Message> inbox;
    std::vector<std::string> contactList;

    std::string emailAddress;
    ForwardTo* forward;
    MessageType* forwardWhen;
};
```

And here is my Persons.cpp file is:

```
#include "Persons.hpp"

#include "ForwardToOne.hpp"
#include "ForwardToTwo.hpp"
#include "ForwardToThree.hpp"

#include <iostream>

Persons::Persons()
    :emailAddress(""), contactList(), inbox(), messageList()
{
}

Persons::~Persons()
{
    //delete forwardWhen;
    //delete forwardTo;
}

void Persons::addMessageContent(MessageContent mc)
{
    //messageSeen.insert(mc);
}

void Persons::setEmailAddress(std::string email)
{
    emailAddress = email;
}

std::string Persons::getEmailAddress() const
{
    return emailAddress;
}

void Persons::addContact(std::string contact)
{
    contactList.push_back(contact);
}

void Persons::addInboxMessage(Message message)
{
    inbox.push_back(message);
}

void Persons::viewContact(const std::vector<std::string>& contacts)
{
    for(auto i = contacts.begin(); i != contacts.end(); i ++)
    {
        std::cout << *i << std::endl;;
    }
}

void Persons::setMessageTypeOne()
{
    MessageType* forwardWhen = new TypeOne();
}

void Persons::setMessageTypeTwo(unsigned int type)
{
    MessageType* forwardWhen = new TypeTwo(type);
}

void Persons::setMessageTypeThree(unsigned int quality)
{
    MessageType* forwardWhen = new TypeThree(quality);
}

void Persons::setMessageTypeFour(unsigned int type, unsigned int quality)
{
    MessageType* forwardWhen = new TypeFour(type, quality);
}

void Persons::setMessageTypeFive() 
{
    MessageType* forwardWhen = new TypeFive();
}

void Persons::setForwardTypeOne(unsigned int strategy)
{
    ForwardTo* forward = new ForwardToOne(strategy);
}

void Persons::setForwardTypeTwo(unsigned int strategy)
{
    ForwardTo* forward = new ForwardToTwo(strategy);
}

void Persons::setForwardTypeThree(unsigned int strategy)
{
    ForwardTo* forward = new ForwardToThree(strategy);
}

const std::vector<std::string>& Persons::getContactList() const
{
    return contactList;
}

void Persons::bumpContact()
{
    std::vector<std::string> tempList = getContactList();
    std::string tempContact = tempList.at(0);
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i <= tempList.size(); i ++)
    {
        if(i == tempList.size())
            tempList.at(--i) = tempContact;
        else
            tempList.at(--i) = tempList.at(i);
    }
}

void Persons::addMessageSeen(Message message)
{
    messageList[*message.getMessageContent()] = message.getMessageContent()->getUniqueID();
}

void Persons::printPersonsObj()
{
    std::cout << "PERSONS OBJECT!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "E-mail Address: " << emailAddress << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

std::list<Message> Persons::getInbox() const
{
    return inbox;
}

MessageType& Persons::getForwardWhen() const
{
    return *forwardWhen;
}

ForwardTo& Persons::getForwardTo() const
{
    return *forward;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incomplete type normally means that at the point at which you are trying to use getForwardTo, you have not fully declared the ForwardTo class. Indeed in your persons.hop there is only a forward declaration.

Make sure you have included the header that fully declares ForwardTo in the file containing the call site.

Comment: I added the #include "ForwardTo.hpp" in the Message dispatcher class and it worked. Thank you. However, I was assuming that becauses Persons.hpp includes each of the forward strategies (`#include ForwardOne/Two/Three`), each of which contain "ForwardTo.hpp" would suffice? Why doesn't this work?

Comment: At least in the person.hpp you pasted in your question, ForwardOne/Two/Three were not included. It should work if they are.

Answer (score 2):

`getForwardTo()` returns a `T&`, just use the `.` to access `forwardMessage()`

Comment: I've tried both the `.` operator and the `->` operator, and neither are detecting the `forwardMessage()` function.

Comment: @LeoVannini Well they had better be because `getForwardTo()` returns `ForwardTo&`, so as long as `forwardMessage()` exists in `ForwardTo` and there is proper access specifier for it, it will be picked up by both Intellisense AND your compiler.

Comment: @LeoVannini Do you have `forwardMessage()` in `ForwardTo`?

Comment: @LeoVannini (Also, just press compile and see what it says, maybe you have like misdefined `forwardMessage()` in your `ForwardTo` class), screw intellisense.

Comment: Yes. Forward to reads

`class ForwardTo
{

public:

 virtual ~ForwardTo() { };
 
        virtual std::vector<std::string> forwardMessage(Persons& person , Message& message) = 0;


};`

Comment: @LeoVannini What does the compiler say if you try to compile with the `.`?

Comment: See the thing is, I access my other pointer that literally does the EXACT same thing as this one stated above the same way:

`listOfPersons.at(i).getForwardWhen().forwardMessage(temp)`

Comment: `error C2228: left of '.forwardMessage' must have class/struct union`                     `error c2027: use of undefined type 'ForwardTo'`

Comment: @LeoVannini You have mess in your header / source files then. Missing an include or something.

Comment: @0x499602D2 sure. is there anything in particular I can post?

Comment: @0x499602D2 added my Persons.hpp/cpp